# Linking HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have kittenbook.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> My First Program! </title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Hello, World, Great to see you!!! :) </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="kittenbook.js"></script>
</body>
```

and kittenbook.js

```
alert('Hello, dude!');
```

But the JS file doesn't produce any difference when I open the HTML file in my browser (supposed to make a window appear with the text). They're in the same folder and I thought I copied everything from the book correctly.

Comment: Look at the dev tools (Console & Network tabs) for issues.

Comment: You can open dev tools in most browser with Right click > Inspect Element and then looking for the console tab

Comment: is kittenbook.js in the same root as kittenbook.html? And close the html plase </html>

Comment: @Roy: He says it is in the question (and remember that `</html>` is entirely and officially optional).

Comment: try to specify the src as `src="./kittenbook.js"`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In fact `<html>` it also optional... which is weird but that's the way it is :D

Comment: That looks right, and if they're in the same folder, that's where they should be. So yeah, you'll need to look at the console (best to have it open during dev anyway). Ctrl+Shift+I or F12 or (on a Mac) Ctrl+Cmd+I.

Comment: Made a JSFiddle for you to show it working: [https://jsfiddle.net/1879g72y/](https://jsfiddle.net/1879g72y/) however this doesn't solve the issue you are having, just shows your JS is correct.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: And several others, I know. :-)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri: There's no reason for that.

Comment: Here is working plunker for the same.

https://plnkr.co/edit/jaXBbgpJq5t2Hrs95lwn?p=info

Comment: check for pop up blockers!

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is unnecessary.

Comment: Might be that the browser is blocking alerts?

Comment: Make sure the file name is correct, and maybe add a `console.log()` to your js file.

Comment: @BnMk: You could be onto something there, though it doesn't happen to me with Chrome.

Comment: @BnMk Pop-up blockers will not block alerts.

Comment: @torazaburo No, but Chrome (at least) gives the option to block alerts for a given site, and `file:///` would be treated as one big "site".

Comment: Have you tested the code in different browsers? Which browser(s) are you testing with?

Comment: Could you kindly provide a listing of the directory, either in text or image form?

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian Where do you see any jQuery in this question??

Comment: @AmarnathBalasubramanian That's it, jQuery is missing! All pages must load jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For security reasons, some browsers do not allow JavaScript to run when loading an HTML file directly from your computer. Older versions of Internet Explorer in particular will show a message indicating a "blocked ActiveXElement" or similar such text, which you must manually allow.

It's possible that your settings are such that local JavaScript is fully disallowed. As shown by several people in comments, your code itself is fine, so it's most likely a security/configuration issue here.

Another possibility is that you have, in the past, checked the "Prevent this site from showing further dialogs" (wording may differ based on browser), which is a feature intended to prevent spam sites from "locking you in" with a hundred `alert`s. You may need to clear site settings if this is the case.

Comment: This answer is a valiant attempt, but the most likely real-world scenario is kittenworld.js not having read permissions, or not being in the right place even thought the OP insists it is, or a spelling error, or something similar.

Comment: @torazaburo Speaking from experience, it does. It's saved as a site setting and applies to all future visits to the same origin.

Comment: @Niet: Not on Chrome. It survives a page refresh, but not closing that tab and opening a new one with the same page. (I was sure, but I also tested before posting this comment.)

Comment: You're right, comment edited.

Comment: @Werner Did you accept this answer because this was in fact the problem? Which of the reasons applied? Do share with us.

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved it, as you say the code was fine but the JS was blocked in browser! I'm 15 minutes into programming but am really looking forward to learning it :)

Comment: I'll add one to my "clairvoyant answer" count, shall I? Welcome to the world of coding and I hope you have as much fun as I do with it!